# Python: изменение константы во внешней библиотеке

Tags: python

Представим, что есть какая-то внешний модуль, выкачавыемый через PIP, и в нем есть следующие строки:

```
TIMEOUT = 50

def test_const():
    print(TIMEOUT)
```

Как без изменения внешнего модуля, поменять эту константу? Пробовал так, не помогло:

```
from out_module import test_const

out_module.TIMEOUT = 10
test_const()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from out_module import test_const
```

импортирует только функцию test_const в глобальные переменные.
Для того чтобы появилась константа **TIMEOUT** в глобальных переменных надо импортировать весь модуль, либо так

```
from out_module import test_const
import out_module

out_module.TIMEOUT = 10
test_const()
```

либо так

```
import out_module

out_module.TIMEOUT = 10
out_module.test_const()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, получилось)